# Safari iOS Responsive Broken

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I've coded a site with the following Grid layout:

```
    Grid
*/

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {

  .col {
    flex: 1;
  }

}
```

It is working beautifully in all my browsers and devices with the exception of Safari on iOS... It is super strange and I've never run into it before.

You can view the site at: https://etmartinkazoo.github.io/evolution/

You can view the repository with code at: https://github.com/etmartinkazoo/evolution

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your site doesn't display correctly on the latest version of Safari either. I would suggest prefixing your css to make sure you're getting the same layout in (all) browsers.

Here are some sass mixins that will allow you to do this in a simple way

```
@mixin flexbox() {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

@mixin flex($values) {
  -webkit-box-flex: $values;
  -moz-box-flex:  $values;
  -webkit-flex:  $values;
  -ms-flex:  $values;
  flex:  $values;
}

@mixin order($val) {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: $val;  
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: $val;     
  -ms-flex-order: $val;     
  -webkit-order: $val;  
  order: $val;
}

.wrapper {
  @include flexbox();
}

.item {
  @include flex(1 200px);
  @include order(2);
}
```

Have a look at this link for more examples. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

For more information on sass, go here http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: The prefixes are needed only if you're targeting _older_ browsers that had early support for flexbox with the prefix. The _Latest_ versions of Safari don't need the prefix — unprefixed `flex` CSS is supported on Safari for iOS versions 9.3 and later, and Safari 9.1 and later on macOS http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: It seems that my problem is elsewhere then... hmm... I'm totally stumped.

Comment: So I used 'Bourbon' to add vendor prefixes to all of my flexbox elements and it is not that... Hmm...